# JSF / CSS attribute conflicts

Tags: jsf

It's our first JSF app, and I'm in the middle of integrating our graphic designer's CSS into our facelets files. He tells me that he needs the **name** and **id** attributes of the input tags to be the same as the **for** attribute of the label tag.

His request:

```
<label for="username">User Name:</label>
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" />
```

However, when JSF code renders the HTML, I get extra identifiers in these attributes.

My facelet code:

```
<label for="username">User Name:</label>
<h:inputText value="#{login.username}" id="username" name="username" />
```

Final XHTML that's sent to the browser:

```
<label for="username">User Name:</label>
<input id="j_id2:username" type="text" name="j_id2:username" />
```

It makes sense to me from a JSF standpoint, but is there a way for me to meet our graphic designer's request and make everyone happy? Or is this a bad JSF oversight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the JSF outputLabel tag, which should handle the ids automatically:

```
<h:inputText id="username">
    <h:outputLabel for="username" value="User Name: "/>
</h:inputText>
```

**Edit:** To avoid confusion: You can also put the outputLabel outside the inputText Element. I just use it mostly like this.